# Nikon Camera Control Pro "No camera was detected"

Tags: nikon, tethering

I'm posting this as question & answer because Google was no help at all for what turned out to be such a simple 'fix'.

Connecting the camera to the computer showed it as being seen by the OS, but no amount of pushing or poking seemed to make Camera Control Pro 2 be able to detect it. The app would simply show the error "No camera was detected" & hang there. The only way out was to force quit.

This symptom survived reboots & also updating the app [in all I tried 3 different versions].

How do you make the Camera Control Pro application recognise your camera?

Adding keywords Capture & Tethering, as my own google-fu couldn't find this again next time I needed it;)

Tested only on Mac with Nikon D5500.

Comment: Telling us which specific Nikon camera you were using would make this question more valuable to a number of readers looking for a wide variety of answers, seeing as how Nikon differentiates its models by whether or not they can be tethered and with how much functionality if they can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Turn the camera off before connecting to USB.

That simple.

I eventually went through the manual page by page & that was the only thing I hadn't done.

Switch it on again once connected, then CCP will immediately identify & connect to it.
Whether you connect before or after launching CCP appears to make no difference.

Once connection has been established for that session, it then appears you can re-connect at any time & it will still be recognised - it's just that first time.

Needless to say, it was one heck of a "D'oh!" moment. I just hope it may be of some help to future Googlers.

This was tested only on Mac & only on a D5500.
I could not repro reports of it not working if other USB devices are connected. I always have at least half a dozen other things permanently connected. It *may* require that the camera tether goes on its own bus - i.e. connect straight to the computer, not through a hub.

I would appreciate confirmation (or otherwise, with details) of it working on Windows or with other Nikon cameras.

Comment: Also, do NOT have any other USB cable connected to the MAC (like for charging your phone).

Comment: Interesting - never thought of that one. I have a dozen devices hung off my machine at all times, didn't seem to come into play at all.

Comment: What is it about additional USB use that would cause the OS to not recognize the attached camera?

Comment: What Nikon camera model?

Comment: Isn't working for me on Camera Control Pro 2 (2.31.0). No matter the order, if the D750 is on and connected to my Mac, CCP freezes. Turning the camera off or disconnecting USB unfreezes CCP (menus and and minimize/close buttons register clicks stored up while it was frozen). Bizarre.